# How to highlight a non-ascii keyword using the listings package?

Tags: listings, unicode, highlighting, input-encodings, keywords

I'm trying to highlight a couple of keywords which contain non-ASCII characters using the listingsutf8 package. This is the relevant part of my document:

```
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8x,
    keywords={Funcionalidade, Para, Como, Eu, Contexto, Cenário, Dado, Quando, Então},
    literate=%
{á}{{\'a}}1
{ã}{{\~a}}1
{ç}{{\c{c}}}1
{é}{{\'e}}1
{ê}{{\^e}}1
{õ}{{\~o}}1
{ó}{{\'o}}1
}
```

The ASCII only keywords are being highlighted correctly, but the `Cenário` and `Então` keywords are not. I have also tried with `emph` and changing `inputencoding`, but it doesn't work either:

```
\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
    emph={Cenário, Cen\'ario, Cenario},emphstyle={\bfseries}
}
```

If it's relevant, the listing I'm trying to highlight comes from a separate file, using the `\lstinputlisting` command. If I had to guess, I would say that it has something to do with the `literate` params.

Comment: The highlight for Cenário will work just fine if you use XeLaTeX -- if it's suitable for your workflow, that is.

Comment: The detection of keywords in **listings** doesn't work well with UTF-8 encoded files. With latin1 encoding, specifying `Cenário` as keyword does what you want. Please, try providing a minimal example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use XeLaTeX right now. I have updated the question with a more concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [listingsutf8](http://ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8) package from the [oberdiek](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) bundle. It offers a workaround exactly for the `\lstinputlisting` command.

Comment: I have tried (and edited the question to reflect the changes I have made), but even with the `listingsutf8` package the keyword is not being highlighted.

Comment: Too bad. And I have no other idea.